# Replacing values >2 and <-2 with 0 in excel

Tags: excel

I want to replace values >2 and <-2 with 0 in excel. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: < -2 included to < 2. Do you mean just "< -2" or ">2 or <-2"?

Comment: I want any value which is < -2 or <2 should be rplaced with 0. cheers

Comment: Any number less than -2 already is less than 2, just because -2 < 2. So, simple condition <2 can be used. But, now the question state >2 OR <-2, I think question was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use [if function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb). I am showing you an example for cell A1:

```
=IF(OR(A1>2,A1<-2),0,A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in a formula,

```
=IF(ABS(A2)>2,0,A2)
```

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, I think it wants to be `ABS(A2)>2`

Comment: @Trengot - you are correct .. :) Got those flipped. I'll fix my post.

Comment: =IF(ABS(A2)>2,0,A2) it working for one column; however how i should use this formula to look for these values in whole excel sheet. with multiple columns. thanks in advance

Comment: @user3459293: the formula is "relative" if you put it in cell H2, then copy it to H3, it will change to `=IF(ABS(A3)>2,0,A3)`. Likewise, if you copy it to I2, it will change to `=IF(ABS(B2)>2,0,B2)`.  So you build the columns somewhere (possibly even a new sheet if it's that large a task), and copy/paste the formula around.  ie On sheet2, cell A1: `=IF(ABS(Sheet1!A1)>2,0,Sheet1!A1)` it's remapping values from sheet1. You can then copy/paste that formula across sheet 2, and "remap" the values from sheet1.